# GetX, GetY onTouch event pass to onCreate method

Tags: android

I am using **onTouch listener on imageView**, using which i get value of **x** and **y**. My wish is to get back these value in other function say onCreate. How can i do this?

**Code:**

```
public void color() {
final Bitmap operation = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //get x,y position
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thats true its not possible get these values in onCreate method. However my purpose is to get x,y and to plot corresponding row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because onTouch is a listener.. so you don't know when it will be called. So the app may crash if you used these variables in the onCreate method while the listener is never called..

But you can create a method that takes x and y as parameters and do whatever you want in it like this :

imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //get x,y position
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    doSomething(x, y);
    return true;
}
});

public void doSomething(int x, int y) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y, Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks was exactly looking something like this